# Multi-Country Using .htacces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to achieve any one of the following:

1. `http://ca.domain.com/Category/SubCategory` -> `http://www.domain.com/index.php?country=ca&category=Category&subcategory=Subcategory`
2. `http://www.domain.com/ca/Category/SubCategory` -> `http://www.domain.com/index.php?country=ca&category=Category&subcategory=Subcategory`

I have browsed around but unfortunately haven't been able to figure out any working solution. For the first kind I tried the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.domain.com/index.php&country=%1&category=$1 [L]
```

The issue with sub domain is that it doesn't redirect anywhere at all. I read around and it says I need to setup wildcard virtual host. I haven't been able to figure out how to do that on godaddy. So not sure how to do it.

As for the second kind, I used the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)/ home.php?country=$1&category=$2 [B]
```

But that didn't work for me either. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Thank you

As for Category & Subcategory, Subcategory is kind of mandatory. So it should also work for following link:

1. `http://www.domain.com/ca/Toronto/Programming` -> `http://www.domain.com/index.php?country=ca&location=Toronto&subcategory=Programming`
2. `http://www.domain.com/ca/Programming` -> `http://www.domain.com/index.php?country=ca&location=&subcategory=Programming`

I am not quite sure as to how to tell .htaccess if it is $1=subcategory or $2=subcategory since they switch in scenario 1 & 2.

Thanks to immense help from @anubhava I have reached to the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=%1&category=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=%1&location=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=$1&category=$2&subcategory=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Can you show your `VirtualHost` config for subdomains to show how they  are setup?

Comment: @anubhava I have no idea where the VIrtualHost config is located. I would appreciate if you could guide me as to where to find it. Thanks

Comment: You will need to ask your server admins for that. Also you can create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://subdomain.domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: I have an account with GoDaddy. I doubt they will be too helpful with that. I uploaded info.php with phpinfo() code. And when I tried to access it using subdomain.domain.com it gave DNS error "The server at subdomain.domainname.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed." If possible can you kindly guide me how to use second option in case subdomain solution requires contacting GoDaddy? Since they aren't the most accommodating bunch.

Comment: Well then it means your subdomain is not even a registered domain. You need to do that first before doing anything in rewrite rules.

Comment: You mean I have to create a subdomain for each country? Because Yes I haven't done that.

Comment: Yes that's right for all the countries you want to support.

Comment: Ok just did that. and got the following as document_root /home/saadbashir/public_html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have these rules in root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?country=%1&category=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?country=%1&category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?country=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?country=$1&category=$2&subcategory=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried to access using both formats but unfortunately it returns 404 error. http://pk.domain.com/category and http://domain.com/pk/category

Comment: The subdomain rule has worked. The other one still gives 404 error

Comment: On trying to run ajax I am getting following error any idea why?
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.domain.com/ajax.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://pk.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Actually this rule won't impact your Ajax requests. If problem still persists please open a new question with all the details and link to this question.

Comment: I figured out if I used complete path then it wouldn't give the error so for now I am just relying on that. Meanwhile I have linked another question to this and would appreciate if you could give it a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804053/redirect-subdomain-to-a-specific-page