# Redirect Subdomain to a specific page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to have http://pk.domain.com to be redirected to http://www.domain.com/home.php?country=pk and similarly http://www.domain.com/pk/ to http://www.domain.com/home.php?country=pk

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=%1&category=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=%1&location=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=$1&location=$2&category=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This question is linked to [Multi-Country Using .htacces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716718/multi-country-using-htacces/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 rules for landing page before other rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ home.php?country=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ home.php?country=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=%1&category=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=%1&location=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ adlisting.php?country=$1&location=$2&category=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```